# Android Studio parse Tuples like from javascript function

Tags: android, json, tuples

I want to use some IOT from some web API using android, but I couldn't write into java from java script, is there any way to convert my javascript into java. Sorry for my bad english, any help will be appreciated.
Here is my javascript code:

```
function On(){
    $.ajax ({
        url : 'http://api.arkademy.com:3000/v0/arkana/device/IO/pastibisa/gpio/control',
        type : 'POST',
        headers : {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'authorization': 'Bearer OTc4Njk4NDY1LjM1MTgwNzc6'
        },
        data : JSON.stringify({
            "controls":{"4":1}
        })

    });
}
```

and this is my android code :

```
private void request(){
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: 1");
        URL url = new URL("http://api.arkademy.com:3000/v0/arkana/device/IO/pastibisa/gpio/control"); 
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: 2");
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("authorization", "user password");
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); // here you are setting the `Content-Type` for the data you are sending which is `application/json`
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST"); // here you are telling that it is a POST request, which can be changed into "PUT", "GET", "DELETE" etc.
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: 4");
        httpURLConnection.connect();
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: 5");
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        String coba = "41";
        jsonObject.put("controls",);
        Toast.makeText(this,jsonObject.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: 6");
        wr.writeBytes(jsonObject.toString());
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```